# How to triggered send an email and also create a subscriber at the same time with Marketing Cloud REST API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have a TriggeredSend event already configured on Marketing Cloud account and the option to add new subscribers to All Subscribers list. The POST request url is:  https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:CUSTOMER_KEY/send?access_token=SOME_TOKEN

with this JSON body:

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "user@domain.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "user@domain.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "email": "user@domain.com",
                "user_id": "1",
                "first_name": "Amin",
                "last_name": "Jade"
            }
        }
    },
    "OPTIONS": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

I am able to trigger the email send event and receive the email but I don't see the subscriber added to the list. Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify what list the triggered emails write to, edit the Triggered Send Definition created in Marketing Cloud.

The configuration page contains a section where you can specify the list to add/update subscribers on, see the screenshot below.  In this example, subscribers are added to the All_Subscribers list.  If you want your email trigger to update the subscriber attributes on existing records, then also select the **Update Subscribes** checkbox.

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you @david it worked as expected. Sorry for being late to reply.